# "A lot of meals consumed are processed" vs "A lot of consumed meals are processed"

Tags: participles

Is there a big difference if I put the word "consumed" before the noun?

A lot of meals consumed are processed

vs

A lot of consumed meals are processed

Are both of the above structures correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A lot of meals consumed are processed
> vs
> A lot of consumed meals are processed
>
> Is there a big difference if I put the word "consumed" before the noun?

Yes, there is a big difference.

---

1. 

*A lot of meals consumed are processed*

"consumed" here is a hidden passive. We could expand it to

*A lot of meals consumed by people are processed*

---

2. 

*A lot of consumed meals are processed*

In this case "consumed" is adjectival. It describes the type of meal that is processed.

---

I partly agree with @Old Brixtonian. In case 2, the sentence tells us the order of events.  It says that meals that have been consumed are then processed. This is true of course because meals *are* processed - by the digestive system! However I don't think that is what you want to say.

So your first sentence makes better sense but it is not perfect. It says that many processed meals are eaten but implies that a lot of processed meals are not eaten: presumably they are thrown away. Undoubtedly that is true. Some people forget to eat processed meals or don't like them and then throw them in the bin. Some processed meals are discarded by the sellers if they have gone out of date.

---

> Are both of the above structures correct?

Correct in what way? Yes, they are both *grammatically* correct and perfect English. The question is, what do you want them to *mean*? Just because the grammar is correct does not mean a sentence makes sense.

So, it depends what you are trying to say. This is why context is so important in English. We need more than just a single sentence to know what your intention is.

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much for your help!! When could I omit the words "that are" like you did in the examples below? A lot of meals that are consumed have been processed. Or A lot of meals consumed are processed ones.

Comment: I still can't answer because I don't know what you intend to convey. Mainly I don't understand the inclusion of the word "consumed".  Most meals *are* consumed whether they are processed or not.  *"A lot of meals consumed are processed"* is good English but why can't you simply say, "A lot of meals are processed"?  We still need to understand the point you want to make, not just the form of words. If you change the order or number of words in a sentence, you will change the meaning so we need to know what you *mean*.

Comment: I want to say that we usually eat fast food, which has already been processed.

Comment: Then I would say, "A lot of what we eat is processed" or "A lot of what people consume is processed."

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You are asking whether 'A lot of buried people are ill' is better than 'A lot of people buried are ill.' Neither is right!

The problem is the order of the **events**, not the order of the words. The meals are processed *before* they are consumed. So you might say:

A lot of processed meals are consumed.

Or

A lot of meals that are consumed *have been* processed.

Or

A lot of meals consumed are processed ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have one more question. When could I omit the words "that are" like you did in the examples below?
A lot of meals that are consumed have been processed.
Or
A lot of meals consumed are processed ones.